# awk command to create a column based on the values in another two columns

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with two columns like:

```
12 c
16 a
50 b
32 b
15 c
25 c
...
```

I want to sort the table first based on second column, then descending sort the first column, then create the third column with 'rank.word'.

so output should look like:

```
16 a 1.a
50 b 1.b
32 b 2.b
25 c 1.c
15 c 2.c
12 c 3.c
...
```

the sorting part is easy, but any idea how to get the third column with basic shell command like awk?

Comment: Welcome to SO, not clear please be clear in your question add more details to it.

Answer (score 3):

**`sort`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
sort -k2 -k1nr file | awk '{ print $1, $2, ++a[$2]"."$2 }'
```

The output:

```
16 a 1.a
50 b 1.b
32 b 2.b
25 c 1.c
15 c 2.c
12 c 3.c
```

Comment: elegant, works well. but can i ask a dump question: what is `++a` doing?

Comment: @jar-jar, it's called pre-increment operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{if($2 != prev) idx=1;else idx++;prev=$2;print $1 " " $2 "." idx}'`

Answer (score 0):

One in GNU awk (2d array, `for` traverse order). It SEEMS to work at least with the data you provided but let me know if it didn't work with your real data.

```
$ awk '{
    a[$2][$1]++                               # hash data to a, count duplicates 
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"      # start with ordering $2 
    for(i in a) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc" # then $1
        for(j in a[i])
            for(k=1;k<=a[i][j];k++)           # handle duplicates
                print j,i,++c[i] "." i        # output
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_asc_asc"  # set order for $2 again
     }
}' file
16 a 1.a
50 b 1.b
32 b 2.b
25 c 1.c
15 c 2.c
12 c 3.c
```

<s>Of course it fails if there are duplicate value pairs.</s> It won't fail for duplicates anymore.